# Can I base a word template on another template

Tags: vba, ms-word

For the purposes of branding, our Word normal.dot template is updated via the login script. This pains me terribly, because I have a number of very useful VBA macros that I want to have access to. Specifically, I have two macros that I add to the Quick Access Toolbar in the title bar that I use all the time.

From what I understand, those macros can only be taken from the document itself or from the template it is based on.

What I am looking for, is a way to either:

1. Add a QAT button to a macro in another file somewhere.
2. Base all my documents on a new template (call it abnormal.dot) which in turn is based on normal.dot, so it can retain the macros even when normal.dot is overwritten.
3. Any other way of achieving my goal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional templates to your Word Application.

Go to Developer Tab on the Ribbon >> Templates section >> press Document Templates...

In new window on Template page you will find Add button on the right- add there some additional templates. This should help.